# How to render more than one dynamic sections / includes / yields in master template using laravel 5.4.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

i am new to laravel and working on my first project in laravel 5.4.6. I have a problem that is how to render multiple dynamic sections / include / yield content into master template. I have already used @section('content') but need more sections( which have dynamic data from database) to show on my layout page. Below is my problem details:

1- Route

```
   Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
   Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showIndex'); 
   Route::get('/index', 'HomeController@showIndex');});
```

2- master.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@yield('title')-Al Quraish Publications</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="Author" content="" />

        <link href="favicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/png">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <link href="{{asset('assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="{{asset('assets/css/font-awesome.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="{{asset('assets/plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="{{asset('assets/plugins/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="{{asset('assets/plugins/owl-carousel/owl.transitions.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="{{asset('assets/plugins/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="{{asset('assets/css/animate.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="{{asset('assets/css/superslides.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <link href="{{asset('assets/plugins/revolution-slider/css/settings.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <link href="{{asset('assets/css/essentials.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="{{asset('assets/css/layout.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="{{asset('assets/css/slider.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="{{asset('assets/css/layout-responsive.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="{{asset('assets/css/color_scheme/brown.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><!-- orange: default style -->

        <link href="{{asset('assets/css/color_scheme/brown.css')}}" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="brown" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/modernizr.min.js"></script>
        <link href="assets/css/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>


<div class="top-header"> 
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                   <div class="topleft">
                   <ul class="socials-icons">
                       <li><a href="https://web.facebook.com/AlQuraishPublishers?_rdr" target="_blank">
                       <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a></li>
                       @if(\Auth::check())
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{url('admin')}}"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Dashboard</a>

                            </li>
                        @else
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{url('login')}}"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Log In</a>

                            </li>
                        @endif
                    </ul> 
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="topright">
                        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> 92 42 37668958 , 37652546 , 37361439 &nbsp; 
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> <a class="wht" href="mailto:info@alquraish.com">info@alquraish.com</a>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <!-- TOP NAV -->
        <div class="pos-absolute"> 
                <header id="topNav" style="height: 100px !important;"><!--data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100" -->

                    <div class="container">
                     <!-- Top Header -->

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <!-- Mobile Menu Button -->
                        <button class="btn btn-mobile" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-main-collapse">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                        </button>

                       <!-- Logo text or image -->
                        <!-- Logo text or image -->
                        <a class="logo" href="index.html">
                            <img src="assets/images/logo.png"> 
                        </a>

                        <!-- Top Nav -->
                        <div class="navbar-collapse nav-main-collapse collapse pull-right">
                            <nav class="nav-main mega-menu">
                                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-main scroll-menu" id="topMain">
                                    <li><a href="{{url('/index')}}">Home</a></li>

                                    <li><a href="{{url('/about')}}">About Us</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{url('/books')}}">Books</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{url('/order')}}">Order Now</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{url('/contact')}}">Contact Us</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Top Nav -->

                    </div>
                </header>
        </div>

        <!-- WRAPPER -->
        <div id="wrapper" >

            <!-- REVOLUTION SLIDER -->
            <div class="fullwidthbanner-container roundedcorners pos-reletive">
                <div class="fullwidthbanner">
                    <ul>    

                        <li data-transition="curtain-2" data-slotamount="5" data-masterspeed="700">
                            <img src="assets/images/sliders/1.jpg" alt="" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="left top" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                        </li>

                        <li data-transition="curtain-2" data-slotamount="5" data-masterspeed="700">
                            <img src="assets/images/sliders/2.jpg" alt="" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="left top" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                        </li>

                        <li data-transition="3dcurtain-vertical" ddata-slotamount="15" data-masterspeed="300" data-delay="9400">
                            <img src="assets/images/sliders/3.jpg" alt="" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="left top" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                        </li>

                        <li data-transition="3dcurtain-vertical" ddata-slotamount="15" data-masterspeed="300" data-delay="9400">
                            <img src="assets/images/sliders/4.jpg" alt="" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="left top" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                        </li>

                        <li data-transition="3dcurtain-vertical" ddata-slotamount="15" data-masterspeed="300" data-delay="9400">
                            <img src="assets/images/sliders/5.jpg" alt="" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="left top" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                        </li>

                        <li data-transition="3dcurtain-vertical" ddata-slotamount="15" data-masterspeed="300" data-delay="9400">
                            <img src="assets/images/sliders/6.jpg" alt="" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="left top" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                    <div class="tp-bannertimer"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /REVOLUTION SLIDER -->


            @section('content')

            @show



            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="scroll-img">
                        <div id="clients-flexslider" class="flexslider home clients">

                            <div class="slider1">
                                  <div class="slide">
                                        <img src="assets/images/gallery-scroll/1.png">
                                        <p>Nazia Kanwal Nazi</p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="slide">
                                        <img src="assets/images/gallery-scroll/2.png">
                                        <p>Riaz Aqab</p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="slide">
                                        <img src="assets/images/gallery-scroll/3.png">
                                        <p>Rizq Shah</p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="slide">
                                        <img src="assets/images/gallery-scroll/4.png">
                                        <p>Malik Safdar Hayat</p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="slide">
                                        <img src="assets/images/gallery-scroll/5.png">
                                        <p>Mehwish Iftikhar</p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="slide">
                                        <img src="assets/images/gallery-scroll/6.png">
                                        <p>Fakhira Gull</p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="slide">
                                        <img src="assets/images/gallery-scroll/7.png">
                                        <p>Asia Mirza</p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="slide">
                                        <img src="assets/images/gallery-scroll/8.png">
                                        <p>Mirza Amjad Baig</p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="slide">
                                        <img src="assets/images/gallery-scroll/9.png">
                                        <p>Anwar Ulaiqi</p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="slide">
                                        <img src="assets/images/gallery-scroll/10.png">
                                        <p>Iffat Tahir</p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="slide">
                                        <img src="assets/images/gallery-scroll/11.png">
                                        <p>MA Rahat</p>
                                  </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>  
                    </div> <!--scroll-img ends-->


=> here is i have problem becuase this setion has data from database and giving me the error of " Undefined variable: " 

                    **<div class="col-md-12">
                        @include('layouts.homeWelcomeHeading')

                    </div>**



                </div> <!--row ends-->
            </div>


        </div>
        <!-- /WRAPPER -->

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row padding60">

                        <!-- FORM -->
                        <div class="col-md-6">


<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FAlQuraishPublishers%2F&tabs=timeline&width=800&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="800" height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>



                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h3>Message Board</h3>
                            <h4>Publisher, Books & Magazine Distribution Book Store</h4>
                            <p>Order your favorite Book / Novel And Get 35% Discount...
For Online Order message Us
Book will be delivered to your door step
Free Home Delivery all across Pakistan </p>

                        <form class="white-row" action="#" method="post">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label>Full Name *</label>
                                            <input type="text" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your name." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label>E-mail *</label>
                                            <input type="email" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your email address." data-msg-email="Please enter a valid email address." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="email" id="email">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label>Phone / Mobile *</label>
                                            <input type="text" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your name." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label>Subject *</label>
                                            <input type="email" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your email address." data-msg-email="Please enter a valid email address." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="email" id="email">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <label>Message *</label>
                                            <textarea maxlength="5000" data-msg-required="Please enter your message." rows="10" class="form-control" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <br />

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Submit Message" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-loading-text="Loading...">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>

                        </div>


                    </div>
        </div>

        <section class="cover margin-footer parallax" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.7" style="background-image: url('assets/images/parallax_bg.jpg');">


                <div class="container">
                    <h3 align="center">Our customers have said</h3>

                    <div class="owl-carousel text-center" data-plugin-options='{"items": 1, "singleItem": true, "navigation": true, "pagination": false, "autoPlay": true, "transitionStyle":"fadeUp"}'><!-- transitionStyle: fade, backSlide, goDown, fadeUp,  -->
                        <div class="testimonial">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
                            <cite><strong>Writer Name</strong>, Customer</cite>
                        </div>

                        <div class="testimonial">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
                            <cite><strong>Writer Name</strong>, Customer</cite>
                        </div>

                        <div class="testimonial">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
                            <cite><strong>Writer Name</strong>, Customer</cite>
                        </div>

                        <div class="testimonial">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
                            <cite><strong>Writer Name</strong>, Customer</cite>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>


            </section>  


        <!-- FOOTER -->
        <footer>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <!-- footer content -->
            <div class="footer-content">
                <div class="container">

                    <div class="row">

                        <!-- FOOTER CONTACT INFO -->
                        <div class="column col-md-8">
                            <h3>Title</h3>


                            <p class="contact-desc">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                            </p>

                            <p class="contact-desc">

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.               
                            </p>

                        </div>
                        <!-- /FOOTER CONTACT INFO -->


                        <!-- FOOTER Profile -->
                        <div class="column col-md-4">
                            <h3>Get In Touch</h3>

                            <address class="font-opensans">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="footer-sprite address">
                                       text will be here 
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="footer-sprite phone">
                                        <strong>Landline:</strong> +1234567789<br> 
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="footer-sprite email">
                                        <a href="mailto:info@mail.com"> info@mail.com</a><br>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </address>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /FOOTER Profile -->

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- footer content -->
<!-- copyright , scrollTo Top -->
            <div class="footer-bar">
                <div class="container">
                    <span class="copyright">Copyright &copy; All Rights Reserved.   
                    <span style="display:inline-block; text-align: right; float: right; ">&nbsp; || &nbsp;
                    Powered by: <a href="#" target="_blank"><small>Me</small></a></span>
                    </span>
                    <a class="toTop" href="#topNav">Go To Top <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- copyright , scrollTo Top -->
        </footer>
        <!-- /FOOTER -->


        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery.appear.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery.isotope.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/masonry.js"></script>

     <script src="assets/js/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
     <script src="assets/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">   

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider1').bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        autoControls: true,
        slideWidth: 155,
        minSlides: 2,
        maxSlides: 7,
        slideMargin: 10,
        pager: true,
        moveSlides: 2,

        /*'auto': true,
        'autoControls': true,
        'pager':false,
          'pager':false,
          'infiniteLoop':false,
          'minSlides':1,
          'maxSlides': 3,
          'slideWidth': '210px',
          'slideMargin':5*/
  });
  $('#slider2').bxSlider({
        'auto': true,
        'autoControls': true,
        'adaptiveHeight': true,
        /*mode: 'vertical',*/
});
});

 </script> 

        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/stellar/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/knob/js/jquery.knob.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/superslides/dist/jquery.superslides.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/mediaelement/build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/revolution-slider/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/revolution-slider/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/slider_revolution.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>


    </body>




</html>
```

3- Controller

```
public function showIndex()
{
    //$text = DB::table('content')->get();
    $text = Content::all();
    return view('index', ['ok', $text]);
}
```

Please help me in this problem i am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand from your question if you need multiple dynamic section to be inserted into master, you need multiple yeilds like

```
@yield('content')
@yield('dynamin-1')
@yield('dynamic-2')
.......
.......
```

then in another blade file you need to extend the master and insert the sections like

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
bla bla <strong>bla bla bla....</strong>
@endsection

@section('dynamin-1')
bla bla <strong>bla bla bla....</strong>
@endsection

@section('dynamin-2')
bla bla <strong>bla bla bla....</strong>
@endsection

....
```

so in your case you do not need the `@section('content')` in you master unless you put it consciously! whenever you will put `@section('content')` in a extended `view` this section in `master` will be overridden!

Comment: At extends('layouts.master')

At section('content')
 
At endsection

At section('ok')
 <h2>{{$ok->title}}</h2>
 <p class="lead">$ok->content</p>

At endsection

Comment: I have applied yield to master @yield('ok') but nothing showing any thing

Comment: Actually i have cusomters data into the child view and i want to show it into master page, that is why i am trying to yield / section but still stuck

Comment: hi, laravel caches the view page so first try to clear cache `php artisan view:clear` and if still you have the problem first try with simple like `@section('ok') hello @endsection`

Comment: the problem is still there nothing is showing from the At section('ok') hello Atendsection, what is the problem ??? i have also php artisan view:clear applied

Comment: please give the updated code of master.blade.php and your desired view where you are trying to insert the content into master

Answer (score 1):

Dear i think you are using

```
@section() // instead of yield()
```

make sure you use

```
@yield('content')
@yield('section1')
@yield('section2')
```

in master.blade php

in child pages you can do it like this

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

@endsection

@section('section1')

@endsection

@section('section2')

@endsection
```